# Regex for validate CC number is not validating JCB cards properly

Tags: regex, validation

I have this RegEx for validate CC numbers:

```
^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|5[1-5][0-9]{14}|6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}|(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11})$
```

It works for almost all but it fails for a few ones. Take a quick look to this test that I've made:

```
#American Express
370517943574132 -> passed
372714451742486 -> passed
370010255141385 -> passed
341263547614307 -> passed
343874494387669 -> passed

#VISA
4024007125780444 -> passed
4439944519233615 -> passed
4658355677043536 -> passed
4532926168018906 -> passed
4532249806735728 -> passed

#MasterCard
5524097521691644 -> passed
5367170623993901 -> passed
5553103980950937 -> passed
5549194987582424 -> passed
5141794881796756 -> passed

#JCB 15 digits
180078244412845 -> passed
210013400722277 -> not passed
210082510016250 -> not passed
180056142071970 -> passed
210043823226606 -> not passed

#JCB
3158822586903214 -> not passed
3088687202983378 -> not passed
3158899851849561 -> not passed
3096803356450490 -> not passed
3337852908456769 -> not passed

#Dinners Club
30193567772121 -> passed
30131361923813 -> passed
30198560976769 -> passed
30260244203356 -> passed
36297440059376 -> passed
```

Where is the issue here? Can any give me some help? [Here](https://regex101.com/r/oX0rR4/1) is an example at Regex101

Comment: You do not have a branch for matching JCB numbers at all. I added `2100` alternative for the `JCB15 digits`: https://regex101.com/r/mV2lN7/1, the rest is what you need to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It always puzzles me what people are trying to do with regex. Stuff like this is much more readable and maintanable when done with a language that supports simple `if` statements...

Anyway. When you look at [a visualization of the regular expression](https://regexper.com/#%5E(%3F%3A4%5B0-9%5D%7B12%7D(%3F%3A%5B0-9%5D%7B3%7D)%3F%7C5%5B1-5%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B14%7D%7C6(%3F%3A011%7C5%5B0-9%5D%5B0-9%5D)%5B0-9%5D%7B12%7D%7C3%5B47%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B13%7D%7C3(%3F%3A0%5B0-5%5D%7C%5B68%5D%5B0-9%5D)%5B0-9%5D%7B11%7D%7C(%3F%3A2131%7C1800%7C35%5Cd%7B3%7D)%5Cd%7B11%7D)%24) you will notice that some cases are just missing:

[image]

The last case (supposed to cover the "#JCB 15 digits" block of your input data) lacks the `2100` prefix.

To fix this simply change the part `2131|1800|35\d{3}` to `2131|2100|1800|35\d{3}`.

However the block "#JCB" of you input data is not covered by any case of your regex. It's just missing completely.

You can make that work if you change the same part to `2131|2100|1800|3\d{4}`. Not sure if that is "correct enough" though.

Here is a working example: https://regex101.com/r/mJ3jW7/1

Comment: Can you help adding that `#JCB` missing?

Comment: Nope, sorry. There are like million different rules regarding cc number validation. And sources might even contradict each other. But I will update the answer with a fix that relaxes then constraints. No idea if that will be "correct enough" for your needs.